# Firewall for Windows to work with hosts/websites and wildcards instead of IPs

Tags: windows, windows-7, networking, internet, firewall

I need a Firewall for Windows which could disallow the access to all websites/hosts and allow only to the ones whitelisted instead of working with IPs as built-in Windows Firewall does.

For example, if I allow `github.com/someuser/*`, then the access to all pages of github.com as well to any other host or website should be denied and only the access to all pages under `github.com/someuser` should be allowed including from SSH.

At that only user with admin rights should be able to change the settings of the program, turn it off or uninstall it